# Settings for Bookmark in ICEPDF Java

Tags: java, frameworks, bookmarks, icepdf

I'm using the pdf viewer IcePDF, but when I'm running my application, the bookmark isn't available. I tried with others PDF and it works when the table of content is on the first page only. Can someone help me to find the settings of this functionality ?

EDIT :

Here is the code to use ICEPdf

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String filePath = "myFile.pdf";

    // build a component controller
    SwingController controller = new SwingController();

    PropertiesManager properties = new PropertiesManager(System.getProperties(),
            ResourceBundle.getBundle(PropertiesManager.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BUNDLE));

    properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_UTILITY_PRINT, false); 

    SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller, properties);

    JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();

    // add interactive mouse link annotation support via callback
    controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
            new MyAnnotationCallback(controller.getDocumentViewController()));

    //controller.getDocumentViewController().setDestinationTarget(controller.getDocument().getCatalog().getDestinations().);

    JFrame applicationFrame = new JFrame();
    applicationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    applicationFrame.setTitle("Test ICEPdf");
    applicationFrame.getContentPane().add(viewerComponentPanel);

    // Now that the GUI is all in place, we can try openning a PDF
    controller.openDocument(filePath);

    // show the component
    applicationFrame.pack();
    applicationFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: PLease add a minimal code example to clarify your issue.

Comment: Done @MartinReiche !